# AWS SnsClient.deleteTopic doesn't delete subscriptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

When I use the Java [SNS lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html) provided by AWS and I use the function:

`DeleteTopicResponse deleteTopic(DeleteTopicRequest deleteTopicRequest)`

I expect the `Topic` to be deleted (which it does) and all the `Subscriptions` to be deleted as well (which it doesn't).

Having run this application for a while, we found many 'floating' subscriptions in AWS.

The documentation of [deleteTopic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#deleteTopic-com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.DeleteTopicRequest-) gives me the impression that it should delete all subscriptions:

> Deletes a topic and all its subscriptions. Deleting a topic might prevent some messages previously sent to the topic from being delivered to subscribers. This action is idempotent, so deleting a topic that does not exist does not result in an error.

Any insight on why there are `Subscriptions` without a `Topic` in our SNS?

Is this a bug? or am misunderstanding this method?

How can this be avoided?

*Deleting all subscriptions manually might be a strain on the system, so if possible I would like to avoid that*.

Comment: I have seen this behaviour too, at times. To be sure, you'll probably need to delete the Subscriptions before deleting the Topic.

Comment: This looks like a bug, contact AWS support.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. I would say this is a AWS bug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-cannot-delete-topic-subscription/:

> Note: After three days, Amazon SNS automatically removes subscriptions that are in the Deleted and Pending Confirmation status from your account.

This should include the subscriptions associated with the deleted topic.

Note that you may run into issues recreating the subscription if you try to use the same topic name and endpoint before the previous one was deleted.

Comment: The documentation suggests that this would only remove subscriptions which are themselves in the Deleted and Pending Confirmation status. It does not seem to cover subscriptions that are in the Confirmed status when the topic is deleted.

Comment: Also I can confirm that subscriptions that should have been deleted when the associated topic was deleted are NOT reaped after this three day period.

Answer (score 1):

I can verify this behaviour with an application using SNS for push notifications.

It looks like an AWS bug to me.

Here's a test program (Python) to reproduce it. This requires a valid AWS key id, secret, and region, and a valid platform endpoint.

```py
import time
import boto3

# NOTE -- Edit these values
AWS_KEY_ID = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"
AWS_KEY_SECRET = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"
AWS_REGION = "eu-west-1"
ENDPOINT = "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:1234567890:endpoint/GCM/Application/12345678-abcd-9012-efgh-345678901234"

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_KEY_SECRET,
    region_name=AWS_REGION,
)
sns_client = session.client("sns")

# Create topic, add subscription
topic_arn = sns_client.create_topic(Name="Test_bug")["TopicArn"]
subscription = sns_client.subscribe(
    TopicArn=topic_arn, Protocol="application", Endpoint=ENDPOINT
)["SubscriptionArn"]

# Delete topic
sns_client.delete_topic(TopicArn=topic_arn)
time.sleep(60)

# Check if subscription was deleted
try:
    sns_client.get_subscription_attributes(SubscriptionArn=subscription)
    print("Unexpected behaviour -- subscription still exists")
except sns_client.exceptions.NotFoundException:
    print("Expected behaviour -- subscription deleted")
```

This shows that the subscription is not deleted, even though [the documentation says the opposite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-delete-subscription-topic.html).